# OAuth2 in-browser-app use Authorization grant instead of implicit

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

We have a public API which we would like to protect using OAuth2.

I've been reading up on the specification/documentation, but I still have some questions about the implicit grant.

I understand the implicit grant is used for client-only in-browser-(javascript)-apps. It is less secure and as such the possibilities should be restricted (e.g. read-only access). Also, no refresh tokens should be issued, and the token should not be long-lived.

But what is stopping the creator of the in-browser-(js)-app to use the Authz grant instead of the implicit grant? As the creator of such an app there is a benefit that I can get more permissions to do (destructive) stuff, and get a refresh-token which I can use to get new access_tokens when they expire. This latter is ideal because I won't have to bug my users to login every so often.

This is of course problematic because the refresh_token, client_id and client_secret are easily compromised this way.

So the question essentially revolves around this:
How can I make sure in-browser-only-apps will only use the restricted implicit grant?

Before being able to connect to our api using OAuth, the client/developer must register for a client_id, callback_url, client_secret. It's possible for me (as api owner) to *revoke* this permission if I detect this kind of behaviour. But this means I'll have to check everything manually, and periodically?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to rely on the user-agent header as the client web app cannot influence it (it is the browser sending the requests!)

You may consider denying issuing a token if cliend_id and client_secrets are used in combination with user-agent coming from a browser. You may allow client_id in combination with browser's user-agent but do not issue refresh_token and use a shorter expiration for access_token in such case. (not sure if this would still technically conform to OIDC)

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good solution. Will do some additional research regarding this aspect

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth2 libraries I've seen usually allow configuring which access grant types are available to a given client. The solution here would be to restrict the client to only use implicit (and disallow the authorization code one).

Comment: Still thinking about it in the conceptual phase, but good to know libraries support it. It will indeed be necessary to grant/revoke these grant types per client (Was trying to say this in my last paragraph). I'm looking for strategies to make this as little human-involved as possible. If a developer once creates a desktop app using authz-grant, I want some way to detect/block him from using the same client_id,client_secret in an authz flow for his seperate web-based-app (in which it would be a security breach)